# Importing python custom qtwidgets into Qt Designer PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, qt-designer, qtwidgets

I do have trouble installing custom widgets into QT Designer. I have a WinPython installation up an running and want to add the following widget to my QT Desinger in order to build my shotgun gui https://github.com/shotgunsoftware/tk-framework-qtwidgets

I have read this, but I cannot figure out on how to get these python files as widgets into QT Designer : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html#buildingandinstallingtheplugin I think the directory for the "plugins" could be: C:\WinPython\python-3.5.4.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5-tools\plugins\designer but I am not sure of it.

Step by step description for a dummie greatly appreciated, I tried my best but am ovewrchallenged. Even the guys at work coulnd't help me.

Comment: this really does seem to be a mighty challenge - i don't think it's that you're a dummy, I just think that this functionality has been badly documented and/or badly implemented.

Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Hey thanks for the kind word, unfortunately I didn't find a solution